# Nuxeo Upgrade from 8.10 to 10.10?

Tags: java, nuxeo, ecm

What is the recommended path to upgrade from Nuxeo 8.10 (2016 LTS) to 10.10 (2019 LTS), should I upgrade directly or should I do it in two steps: first to 9.10 and then to 10.10 ?

The [official documentation](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/upgrade-from-lts-2016-to-lts-2017/) only describes the upgrade from one version to the next, not the upgrade of two versions in one step.

Can you please tell me what is the best option and if the answer is "upgrade directly", can you please tell me what is the process to follow?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow this pattern (as suggested by Nuxeo Core Team)

```
 LTS 2016 –> LTS 2017 –> LTS 2019
```

There is a discussion on this topic with Nuxeo team.

https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/dfefbe2689704e428427a1a8fcbf110f/Upgrade-from-6-0-LTS-to-LTS-2019

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that's what I'm going to do.